# access variable of upper/wrapper class

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner at Java so I don't know if what I'm trying to access is an upper/wrapper class. Basically, I have three classes, A, B and C.

**CLASS A.java**

```
public class A{

private String aName;

private B objectB;

}
```

**CLASS B.java**

```
public class B{

    private String bName;

    private C objectC;

    }
```

**CLASS C.java**

```
public class C{

        private String cName;


        }
```

Basically, I have a Class A, which has an object of Class B, which in turn has an Object of class C.
I have an instance of an object of class C. How do I access the variables bName and cName from this instane of object C?

Comment: Java is not my main area but don't you have to import Class A and Class B into Class C before Class C can read any of those A or B variables? Also is there a 4th (Main?) class that holds the instance of Class C?

Comment: Yes, I'm using android so this 4th class is basically the Activity in which I'm accessing the Object C. About the imports, will that give access to the particular instance of class which created the current object?

Comment: Class A must `import classB;` so that `private B someVar;` makes sense. Same for Class B importing Class C to make an instance of `objectC`... When Class C imports the other 2 classes, you then make instances of them. For example : `private A instA;` so with `instA` as reference to the class you could access vars as `myString = instA.aName;` or `myString = instB.bName;` etc...

Comment: @Vc.One Does instA.aName get the variable for a particular instance? There can be difference aNames is what I'm saying. How do I make sure it's specific to the current instance?

Comment: Instances of Classes must have unique names. Use that unique name to access variables. _eg:_ `instA1.aName` or `instA2.aName`. By saying `private B objectB;` you are saying `objectB` is your instance name for Class `B` so to get vars from `B` like bName just do `objectB.bName`...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use getter & setter method for accessing variable bName from instance of c. you can not directly access them as they are private.

"CLASS B.java"

```
public class B{

private String bName;

 public String getbName() {
    return bName;
}

public void setbName(String bName) {
    this.bName = bName;
}

private C objectC;

}
```

You can directly access "cName" variable as this variable is the belong to same obejct of c which you are using to get bName.

Comment: Yes I can do that but I'm using gson to create POJO from a json. So gson deserializes objects on its own and for that I need to have the variables accessed within the object. Or i there a way to set variable in gson?

Comment: If possible, Please post the json also

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for getting access to the instance of **Class B** from **Class C** would be to add a reference to B in C:

**Class C**

```
public class C {

    private String cName;
    private B bObj;

}
```

And then use getters and setters in class B:

**Class B**

```
public class B {

    private String bName;
    private C cObj;

    public String getBName() {
        return bName;
    }

    public void setBName(String newName) {
        this.bName = newName;
    }
}
```

However, do remember that this leads to a circular dependency, which usually is a code smell (it may be OK in this situation though, depending on the overall class hierarchy).

---

The better option would be to implement the Observer pattern between the classes:

**Class C**

```
public class C {

    private String cName;
    private List<Observers> observers; //if you only need one instance, then 
                                       //switch out for a single interface reference

    public void requestWrapperName () {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for(observer: observers) {
            names.add(observer.requestName());
        }
        // code to do what you want with wrapper name
        ...
    }

    public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(obsersver);
    }

}
```

**Observer interface**

```
public interface Observer {
    String requestName();
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B implements Observer {

    private String bName;
    private C cObj;

    // Observer method
    public String requestName() { 
        return bName;
    }
}
```

Now, when you have the instance of C in class B, you can just inject B as an observer into C with `cObj.addObserver(this);` and then request B's name with the method `requestWrapperName();`. Thus avoiding having associations both ways :)